# Search XML/CSV file for specific string, and if exists, then copy/output to new location

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I have a large amount of XML files to go through.  Some of the files contain certain strings (that I am searching for), while the other XML files do not contain the certain string.  How can I open each file to search for the specific string?

If the string exists in the file, I would like to make a copy of the file in another location.  A basic example of the code I have thought of is (but non wrong and skipping some code):

```
inputFile = ('example/nonReducedFiles/%s/%02d/%02d/%s.xml')%(year, month, day, id)
inputFile.read()
if 'exampleString' exists in inputFile:
    outputFile = ('example/reducedFiles/%s/%02d/%02d/%s.xml')%(year, month, day, id)
    writer.writelines(outputFile)
```

I am fairly new to Python, so I am hoping to find something that is not too complex.  If it would be easier, I also have the files in a CSV format.

Comment: Are you sure you need Python for this? In `/bin/sh` it is: `( cd example/nonReducedFiles ; cp --parents $(egrep -lr exampleString .) ../reducedFiles/. ; )`